# How the static resource mapping in server in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My Spring Boot target tree like this:[image]

You can see my `sign.html` is the same as the position as the `css` folder.

Why I need add `sign/` prefix in `href` in `sign.html` to access the css resources not `./`?
[image]

Comment: I don't think you actually need that. Try `href="./css/reset.css"`
Why do you even care about the target Folder. You shouldn't touch that.

Comment: The `./css/reset.css` doesn't work, it will response 404.@MustafaYousef